# Firebase - clear cached subscriptions after .delete()

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When a user logs out, I do:

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().delete(handler: { (error) in })
```

Which should (?) invalidate the token and unsubscribe from all topics.

It works, but logging in with the same device and calling `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()` (from notification when it's ready), I get the same token (not really a problem, but unexpected). However; subscribing to topics (upon login for instance) seems to be cached in the device from the previous login, so it doesn't make a network call, meaning the token will not be associated with any topics on the FCM side. Assume it's the same user doing a relog; the topics he/she wants to subscribe to are the same as before `delete()`.

I can verify this by querying `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/<token>` with the token: Even after calling `subscribeToTopic` in my app, the list of topics remains empty. Normally this call results in the -5 error (described here https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/146) when subscribing to multiple topics, but nothing happens, indicating to me that the application *thinks* it's already subscribed to the topics and hence does nothing.

So - how can I unsubscribe from all topics upon logout, and successfully resubscribe when logging in? Looping the topics and doing `unsubscribeFromTopic` seems a little hacky to me.

Comment: could you try again with the latest SDK that has been released today? (v3.13.0)

Comment: Wow, both errors are gone: The token is removed from FCM, renewed on log in (and not just reissued), resubscription works AND the -5 error is gone. Perhaps update the GitHub thread with an official reply.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can disconnect the user from getting push notifications by doing FiRMessaging.messaging.disconnect()
And connect the user when he logs back in

Comment: That doesn't really solve the issue with being subscribed to the wrong topics (assuming different user logs in). For what it's worth I moved away from topics entirely. I now push 1000 tokens at a time.

Comment: Probably the best thing you can do is store the subscriptions in the user node, when the user logs delete all the instances and retrieve the topics saved in the database and subscribe to them

Comment: The delete method does exactly that. Disconnect does not.

Comment: Hey nickdnk can you tell me exactly what does that instanceid.delete() do?

Comment: It invalidates the device token at FCM, so that you'll get a new token when you instantiate FCM later on (new user for instance).

Comment: So will that delete all the subscriptions from my device? Because I need a way to unsubscribe from all topics

Comment: Yes, delete will accomplish that.